# Regex that says what NOT to match?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I’m wondering how to match any characters **except for** a particular string (call it `"for"`) in  a regex.

I was thinking maybe it was something like this:  `[^for]*` — except that that doesn’t work.

Comment: `[^for]` will be any characters except `f`, `o` and `r`. Is that what you want? Or do you to match anything except the word `for` ?

Comment: yes, i do to match anything except the word for

Comment: You're probably better off either using simple string matching, or matching the word `for` and negating your result.

Comment: By the way - congratulations on selecting the least original title on stack overflow - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/936/most-common-titles

Answer (score 3):

I’m sure this a dup.

One way is to start your pattern with a lookahead like this:

```
(?=\A(?s:(?!for).)*\z)
```

That can be written like this in any regex system worth bothering with:

```
(?x)            # turn /x mode on for commentary & spacing
(?=             # lookahead assertion; hence nonconsumptive
    \A          # beginning of string
    (?s:        # begin atomic group for later quantification
                        # enable /s mode so dot can cross lines    
        (?! for )       # lookahead negation: ain't no "for" here
        .               # but there is any one single code point
    )           # end of "for"-negated anything-dot
    *           # repeat that group zero or more times, greedily
    \z          # until we reach the very end of the string
)               # end of lookahead
```

Now just put that in the front of your pattern, and add whatever else you’d like afterwords. That’s how you express the logic `!/for/ && ⋯` when you have to built such knowledge into the pattern.

It is similar to how you construct `/foo/ && /bar/ && /glarch/` when you have to put it in a single pattern, which is

```
(?=\A(?s:.)*foo)(?=\A(?s:.)*bar)(?=\A(?s:.)*glarch)
```

Comment: This looks over-complicated to me, could you break it down and explain a little?

Comment: @Tim - If I'm not mistaken, that is a local `(?s)` on a group, so the dot matches new-lines. I think it is well supported, though tchrist is probably assuming perl `:)`

Comment: @jb: “Over-complicated”? It’s simply how you express a negated match when you don’t have recourse to auxiliary logic in the surrounding programming language, like simply saying `!/for/ && ⋯`. It’s the standard solution for this problem, and is quite well known. The notation is just basic regex stuff that you can look up in any reference page.

Comment: @tchrist - Does it have an advantage over `\A(?!.*for)`? (assuming dot-all)

Comment: @Kobi: Aha, so the `:` still means "non-capturing group" in this context? That way the `?` is used twice, once for dotall mode `?s` and once for `?:`. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @Tim - Most (or all, except named captures) `(?...)` sub-patterns are non-capturing, I think `:` is just a separator.

Comment: @tchrist, right right, I get that part, I was just looking at the extra `(?=...)` assertion and the `(?s:...)` group and they weren't making since to me.

Comment: @Kobi: A `(?<ɴᴀᴍᴇ>⋯)` group is also a numbered capture group, which is now also available by that ɴᴀᴍᴇ (using the standard Perl and Java [JDK7] notation; your mileage may very). As for why not the shorter negated way, it’s mostly (maybe entirely) because that way you can use it elsewhere in the string, where `\A` wouldn’t be appropriate, or even `\G`, and arbitrary backtrack points like `(*MARK)` are not widely supported. `"foo bar" =~ /(?!.*foo)/` is TRUE but anchored with `"foo bar" =~ /\A(?!.*foo)/` is FALSE; when combining, you may not be at the start of the string, so `\A` wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!for$).*$
```

matches any string except `for`.

```
^(?!.*for).*$
```

matches any string that doesn't *contain* `for`.

```
^(?!.*\bfor\b).*$
```

matches any string that doesn't *contain* `for` as a complete word, but allows words like `forceps`.

Comment: Tim, the problem with that approach is that it assumes you are at the start of the string and are allowed to consume the whole thing. The reason I wrote my solution as I did was so that you could put the assertion wherever you wanted without requiring that it be standalone. The standalone solution never made much sense to me because if you could get away with that, it shouldn’t be hard to add the extra “not” logic around a normal match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check whether the string matches `for`, and negate the result, in whatever language you use (e.g. `if (not $_ =~ m/for/)` in Perl)

Comment: `unless /for/`⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠